# How to install Steam in Mint 19.1?

Tags: nvidia, steam

I'm using Linux Mint 19.1 (Tessa), based on Ubuntu.
So far the only lead I have is a couple of Nvidia driver installation errors. However, other than the Steam issue, and the Nvidia settings app not showing up, the driver seems to be used by the system successfully. I was able to output a movie file with Blender. I ran OBS too. But ultimately, Steam won't run (although it seems installed)
Here is some relevant data:

```
sudo apt install steam
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libnvidia-common-390 libnvidia-common-396 libnvidia-common-410
  libnvidia-common-415 libwayland-client0:i386 libwayland-server0:i386
  screen-resolution-extra
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
Suggested packages:
  steam-devices:i386
Recommended packages:
  libxss1:i386 nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  steam:i386
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/1,311 kB of archives.
After this operation, 4,106 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package steam:i386.
(Reading database ... 289208 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../steam_1%3a1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking steam:i386 (1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23+linuxmint4) ...
Setting up steam:i386 (1:1.0.0.54+repack-5ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.8.3-2ubuntu0.1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-11ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
drpeppercan@Nitro:~$ steam
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2019-03-31 16:02:27] Startup - updater built Nov 23 2016 01:05:42
libGL error: No matching fbConfigs or visuals found
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

---

```
inxi -v2
System:    Host: Nitro Kernel: 4.15.0-46-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: Cinnamon 4.0.10 
           Distro: Linux Mint 19.1 Tessa 
Machine:   Type: Desktop Mobo: Acer model: Nitro N50-600 v: V:1.1 serial: <root required> 
           UEFI: American Megatrends v: R01-A3 date: 05/16/2018 
CPU:       6-Core: Intel Core i7-8700 type: MT MCP speed: 800 MHz min/max: 800/4600 MHz
```

---

```
glxinfo | grep renderer
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
drpeppercan@Nitro:~/Documents$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: NVIDIA Corporation
OpenGL renderer string: GeForce GTX 1060 6GB/PCIe/SSE2
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 418.56
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60 NVIDIA
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 418.56
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
drpeppercan@Nitro:~/Documents$ nvidia-smi
Sun Mar 31 20:30:15 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.56       Driver Version: 418.56       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 106...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0  On |                  N/A |
| 40%   39C    P0    27W / 120W |    395MiB /  6075MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1298      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           158MiB |
|    0      1797      G   cinnamon                                      73MiB |
|    0     13428      G   bin/shotcut                                   16MiB |
|    0     16868      G   /usr/lib/nemo-preview/nemo-preview-start       8MiB |
|    0     17241      G   ...quest-channel-token=6126019085776133848   136MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

```
drpeppercan@Nitro:~/Documents$ sudo nvidia-settings
[sudo] password for drpeppercan:         
sudo: nvidia-settings: command not found
```

---

```
apt search nvidia-driver
p   nvidia-driver-390                      - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-390:i386                 - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-396                      - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-396:i386                 - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-410                      - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-410:i386                 - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-415                      - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
p   nvidia-driver-415:i386                 - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
i   nvidia-driver-418                      - NVIDIA driver metapackage                        
v   nvidia-driver-binary                   -                                                  
v   nvidia-driver-binary:i386
```

---

```
apt-cache search nvidia-driver
nvidia-304 - NVIDIA legacy binary driver - version 304.137
nvidia-340 - NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.107
nvidia-384-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-384 - Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-387-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-387 - Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-390-dev - Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-390 - Transitional package for nvidia-driver-390
nvidia-driver-390 - NVIDIA driver metapackage
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
nvidia-driver-396 - NVIDIA driver metapackage
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-396 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
nvidia-headless-390 - NVIDIA headless metapackage
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-390 - NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS
nvidia-headless-396 - NVIDIA headless metapackage
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-396 - NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS
nvidia-driver-410 - NVIDIA driver metapackage
nvidia-headless-410 - NVIDIA headless metapackage
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-410 - NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-410 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
nvidia-driver-415 - NVIDIA driver metapackage
nvidia-headless-415 - NVIDIA headless metapackage
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-415 - NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-415 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
nvidia-driver-418 - NVIDIA driver metapackage
nvidia-headless-418 - NVIDIA headless metapackage
nvidia-headless-no-dkms-418 - NVIDIA headless metapackage - no DKMS
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-418 - NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Comment: Could you edit your question with the output of `ldconfig -p | grep libGL.so`?

Comment: Ultimately I got the driver installed thanks to this tutorial:
Easy Linux Tips Project: NVIDIA: how to install the latest video card drivers
https://easylinuxtipsproject.blogspot.com/p/nvidia.html

And thanks to Paradox's advice: sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-418:i386

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can gather, you are lacking the 32 bits OpenGL libraries that Steam needs to run. You can install them like this :

```
$ sudo apt install libnvidia-gl-418:i386
```

or like this if you want to update them each time you install another proprietary driver version (since it seems you have the old ones still installed - it would be a good idea to purge them):

```
$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-libs-i386:i386
```